# Editing Buttons in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, button

In HTML or CSS, is there a way to edit the size, shape, and overall appearance of buttons, say the code

```
<input type="button" onclick="spam()" value="Spam">
```

but make the button actually look attractive, not gray and small?

Comment: Google "Styling form element with CSS" for dozens if not hundreds of examples and tutorials.

Comment: Just google "styling button with css"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, one approach is to give it a class and use that class to style it.

```
<input class="submit-button" type="button" onclick="spam()" value="Spam">

.submit-button{  
  /* style properties go here */
}
```

To style all buttons the same you could simply use a css selector as follows

```
input[type="button"] {
    /* style properties go here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```
input[type="button"] {
    // your CSS
}
```

or remove the `[type="button"]` to apply to all input...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just give your button a class and go to town with styling.

[Try this.](http://jsfiddle.net/gqZvu/9/)